# Plumber set my bathtub on top of Great Stuff foam. Do I need to pull the tub?

Tags: bathtub, mortar, spray-foam

My floor was about 1/16” off level so the plumber said he couldn’t set the tub into a mortar bed. The tub is acrylic.  He sprayed a can on great stuff foam on the subfloor then set the tub on top of that and used shims on the side to bring it up to level. I’m really nervous that this will fail over time. He assured me that it wouldn’t.

I’m debating whether I need to tear down the cement board I just installed and uninstall the tub, reinstalling with a mortar bed. This would obviously be a setback and I’m not sure how well I’d be able to set the tub myself again. Wondering what y'all think I should do.

Comment: metal or acrylic tub?

Comment: Acrylic tub. I’ll edit the post to specify that.

Comment: You should be more specific about the foam. The "windows and doors" type has little stiffness after it cures. The cheap, ordinary type, "gaps and cracks," seems plenty stiff for your bathtub application based on my experience with it. There even exists a polyurethane foam formulation for installing fence posts.

Comment: It was the regular “gaps and cracks” foam.

Comment: Is "Good Stuff" the generic version of "Great Stuff"?

Comment: That was a typo, It is great stuff.

Comment: Even if your tub is a very deep 20 inch soaker tub, its pressure exerted on the floor through full uniform bedding would be just 0.72 PSI for a 20" column of water plus the weight of the tub itself, which is far less than 1 PSI for acrylic. The Great Stuff Pro product information sheet indicates the product typically develops about 9.3 PSI compressive strength. Supposing the foam developed lots of stable, small cells (rather than collapsing into large cells) it seems like there's a reasonable margin of safety.

Comment: It’s been about a month and I’ve since continued my bathroom renovation. The tub started squeaking slightly a week ago and now the squeak is progressively worse. It squeaks at the right corner of the tub edge on the drain side. I’m debating whether to cut the cement board out (I started my tile on the 2nd row so there’s ~7” of board I could cut to the tub flange) and try resetting it OR go grab some more foam and try drilling a few holes in the subfloor from the basement and shooting in as much foam as I can.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perfectly common modern technique.

You should relax, and keep the plumber's number handy in the not-very-likely event that it "fails."

Me, I use plaster, but I have nothing against foam done correctly. I have a great deal of nasty things to say about people that don't bed tubs, though. I've seen the resulting failures.

It is possible to bed a tub without removing it, by coming in through the back or end wall (and then patching that wall.)

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturers state that mortar must be used, yet you see every excuse to avoid using it.  It's cheap and you only need a five gallon bucket and a paddle with a drill to mix up a bag or two and slap it down.  I just did this and my shower pan is rock solid.  I personally would be expecting it to creak over time, but what are you going to do now?  Pull it up and reset it?  If others have their own experiences with foam, I imagine that you just let it ride and see if it passes the test of time.

Comment: That’s what I’ve concluded as well. Im keeping Ecnerwal’s solution of opening up the wall and backfilling with mortar in my back pocket if it does creak down the road.

Comment: If you need to do that in the future, you would use a bag to push the mortar underneath the pan, like you were icing a cake.